# Pressing SAP.GuiLable

Tags: c#, api, sap-gui

Is it possible to press a SAPFEWSELib.GuiLable using the SAP Gui API? The class does not have a method like Press() available for GuiButtons.

It's also not possible to do it like this:

```
SAPFEWSELib.GuiLable Lbl = GetLable();
(Lbl as SAPFEWSELib.GuiButton).Press(); //Exception thrown!!
```

Any idea?

I can get the coordinate of the lable, calculate its center and click it by Win32 API but I'd like to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

In brief, no, the GUILabel object does not have a Press method.  (It does have GetListProperty, SetFocus, ShowContextMenu, Visualize

However you may find that the label is in a Container or has an Inner Object that can be clicked.  I think you probably have got the wrong element.

I suggest that you review the SAP GUI Scripting API (in the GUI, it is available from the Customise button menu "SAP GUI Scripting Help")

Andy